# How to draw without animation?

Tags: java, android, view

I am using the following code which I got from github [link](https://github.com/hanks-zyh/AnimateCheckBox).

TouchCheckBox.java

```
public class TouchCheckBox extends View {

private Paint mCirclePaint;
private Paint mCorrectPaint;
private int radius;
private int width, height;
private int cx, cy;                    
private float[] points = new float[6];
private float correctProgress;
private boolean isChecked;
private boolean isAnim;
private int animDurtion = 150;

private OnCheckedChangeListener listener;
private int unCheckColor = Color.GRAY;
private int circleColor = Color.RED;

public TouchCheckBox(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public TouchCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TouchCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);

}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public TouchCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

private void init(Context context)
{

    mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mCirclePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    mCorrectPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mCorrectPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mCorrectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mCorrectPaint.setStrokeWidth(dip2px(context, 2));
    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (isChecked)
            {
                hideCorrect();
            } else 
            {
                showCheck();
            }
        }
    });
}


public void setChecked(boolean checked)
{
    if (isChecked && !checked)
    {
        hideCorrect();
    }
    else if(!isChecked && checked)
    {
        showCheck();
    }
}


public boolean isChecked(){
    return isChecked;
}


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    height = width = Math.min(w - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight(),h - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop());
    cx = w / 2;
    cy = h / 2;

    float r = height / 2f;
    points[0] = r / 2f + getPaddingLeft();
    points[1] = r + getPaddingTop();

    points[2] = r * 5f / 6f + getPaddingLeft();
    points[3] = r + r / 3f + getPaddingTop();

    points[4] = r * 1.5f +getPaddingLeft();
    points[5] = r - r / 3f + getPaddingTop();
    radius = (int) (height * 0.125f);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    float f = (radius -height * 0.125f) / (height * 0.5f);
    mCirclePaint.setColor(evaluate(f,unCheckColor,circleColor));
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, mCirclePaint);


    if(correctProgress>0) {
        if(correctProgress<1/3f) {
            float x = points[0] + (points[2] - points[0]) * correctProgress;
            float y = points[1] + (points[3] - points[1]) * correctProgress;
            canvas.drawLine(points[0], points[1], x, y, mCorrectPaint);
        }else {
            float x = points[2] + (points[4] - points[2]) * correctProgress;
            float y = points[3] + (points[5] - points[3]) * correctProgress;
            canvas.drawLine(points[0], points[1], points[2], points[3], mCorrectPaint);
            canvas.drawLine(points[2], points[3], x,y, mCorrectPaint);
        }
    }
}



public void setCircleColor(int color){
    circleColor = color;
}


public void setCorrectColor(int color){
    mCorrectPaint.setColor(color);
}


public void setUnCheckColor(int color){
    unCheckColor = color;
}

private int evaluate(float fraction, int startValue, int endValue) {
    int startInt = startValue;
    int startA = (startInt >> 24) & 0xff;
    int startR = (startInt >> 16) & 0xff;
    int startG = (startInt >> 8) & 0xff;
    int startB = startInt & 0xff;

    int endInt = endValue;
    int endA = (endInt >> 24) & 0xff;
    int endR = (endInt >> 16) & 0xff;
    int endG = (endInt >> 8) & 0xff;
    int endB = endInt & 0xff;

    return ((startA + (int) (fraction * (endA - startA))) << 24)
            | ((startR + (int) (fraction * (endR - startR))) << 16)
            | ((startG + (int) (fraction * (endG - startG))) << 8)
            | ((startB + (int) (fraction * (endB - startB))));
}

private void showUnChecked()
{
    Log.i("TCB","showUnChecked");
    if (isAnim)
    {
        return;
    }

    isAnim = true;
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1).setDuration(animDurtion);
    va.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    va.start();
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue(); // 0f ~ 1f
            radius = (int) ((1 - value) * height * 0.375f + height * 0.125f);
            if (value >= 1) {
                isChecked = false;
                isAnim = false;
                if(listener!=null){
                    listener.onCheckedChanged(TouchCheckBox.this,false);
                }
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    });
}

private void showCheck()
{
    Log.i("TCB","showCheck");
    if (isAnim) {
        return;
    }
    isAnim = true;
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1).setDuration(animDurtion);
    va.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    va.start();
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue(); // 0f ~ 1f
            radius = (int) (value * height * 0.37f + height * 0.125f);
            if (value >= 1) {
                isChecked = true;
                isAnim = false;
                if(listener!=null){
                    listener.onCheckedChanged(TouchCheckBox.this,true);
                }
                showCorrect();
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    });
}

private void showCorrect()
{
    Log.i("TCB","showCorrect");
    if (isAnim) {
        return;
    }
    isAnim = true;
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1).setDuration(animDurtion);
    va.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    va.start();
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue(); // 0f ~ 1f
            correctProgress = value;
            invalidate();
            if(value>=1){
                isAnim = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
private void hideCorrect()
{
    Log.i("TCB","hideCorrect");
    if (isAnim) {
        return;
    }
    isAnim = true;
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1).setDuration(animDurtion);
    va.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    va.start();
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue(); // 0f ~ 1f
            correctProgress = 1-value;
            invalidate();
            if(value>=1){
                isAnim = false;
                showUnChecked();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener)
{
    this.listener = listener;
}

public interface OnCheckedChangeListener
{
    void onCheckedChanged(View buttonView, boolean isChecked);
}


public static int dip2px(Context context, float dpValue) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dpValue * scale + 0.5f);
}


public static int px2dip(Context context, float pxValue) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (pxValue / scale + 0.5f);
}
}
```

I want the view to be static at first view any only animate when I press on it. I have no idea how to draw without animation. I have no idea about drawing anything programmatically.

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`, for more refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Comment: define a handler, and call "reload" or "refresh" function of view recursively inside run of handler

Comment: @Adem recursion will not animate anything, `Animators` are for thing like that, not `Handlers`

Comment: @pskink I meant calling run recursively runnable of handler. animators and other android component does similar things

Comment: yes but it is not recursion, its normal iteration

Comment: sorry, I might be wrong. it is not a recursive call completely. invalidate needs to be post to handler again and again until animation complete

Comment: @pskink I have no idea what you both are talking. Sorry for that. I am little new to android. My main problem is that whenever I scroll my Recyclerview some of my TouchCheckBox are first checked and then goes to unchecked state a moment later automatically. Recyclerview code is alright. Because everything is working fine when I use a default checkbox.

Comment: @Adem yes this is exactly how it works, but still, it is better to use `Animators`

Comment: @MrShadow, onDraw is called by OS. so, you need to trigger it some how. right way is calling "invalidate" of view (TouchCheckBox). so, after you change state of component, you call invalidate. then OS will draw component again, and your onDraw function will be called.

Comment: @Adem I am calling invalidate(). But if u think I am doing something wrong in the code then please edit my code. Please please I beg you.

Answer (score 0):

as I remember, you need to call `View.invalidate` to redraw component. if you call invalidate again and again in a handler, this becomes a animation

```
private boolean isAnimCompleted(){ // you need to check animation is completed some how
    boolean completed = false;
    .
    .
    return completed;
}
public void startAnimManually(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        private Runnable thisRunnable = this;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.invalidate();
            if (!isAnimCompleted()){
                handler.post(thisRunnable);    
            }
        }
    });
}
```